# Git : revert to old version for particular file with checkout command and commit

Tags: git, git-checkout

I want to revert to previous version for a particular file.
I am using following command.

```
git checkcout <commit hash> <file-name>
```

Now I want to commit this file.
I am doing

```
git commit -a.
```

It is giving me following messages

"nothing to commit, working directory clean"

EDIT : All these commit have been pushed to remote repos.

Comment: Check `git status` after `git checkout <commit hash> <file name>`

Comment: Do you need to undo the changes of a commit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command below moves the HEAD pointer to the old commit.

```
 git checkout <commit hash> <file-name>
```

You probably intended to do the following command, which will "revert to previous version for a particular file", without moving the current HEAD.

```
 git checkout <commit hash> -- <file-name>
```

After the command above, `git status` will show the file as being modified.
You can then do `git commit -a` to commit the file on the top of the current commit.

Update: If you had previously moved your HEAD pointer, you most likely want to move it back to your working branch before running the command above and committing. So the full sequence of commands should be:

```
 git checkout master
 git checkout <commit hash> -- <file-name>
 git commit -a
```

Comment: no..git status is showing # HEAD detached at a451114(commit-hash)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: @merlin2011..sorry it was after my command..after your command it is showing as modified..so i guess its "--" which is making difference?

Comment: @shantanu, I always used `--` when trying to check out one file. I did an experiment with a new repository and observed that the `HEAD` had moved when using your command.

Comment: awsome..just one more question..after commit while doing git branch it is showing (detached from <hash>)...how to push this commit into some remote repos..

Comment: I think you want to `git checkout master` (or whatever your working branch is) before you run my command and then run the commit.
What you are seeing is the effect from your command: You moved to an earlier commit and then committed off of that, instead of off of master.